# Run callbacks when user hung up call from IVR

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I used this PHP library [PAGI](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/pagi_tutorial_create_voip_telephony_application_for_asterisk_with_agi_and_php.html) to build an IVR application with Asterisk.
For every call I need to do some cleanups and write something to the database. So I need some callback/handler after user hung up the call.

ASAIK, this library provides some way to detect hangup from user:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, $signalHandler);
```

However this is not going to work after I picked up the call by sending command `ANSWER`. If it is used without `ANSWER`, the above callback does work after the call is hung up!

So I would like to know what is the workaround for my situation?

Comment: you can have 'h' extension in your context which will be called after each hangup. But I think you should not do database operation in 'h' extension.
what about registering a "hangup handler " on each call arrives on asterisk, still not recommended to do database operation on hangup handlers

Comment: Why do you say that handling the signal "doesn't work"? See: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_AGI " A locally executed AGI script will receive SIGHUP on hangup from the channel except when using DeadAGI."

Comment: @marcelog Hi i tried to run one of your examples "nodecontroller/run.php" but `signalHandler` is not called after user hung up. Here is my extensions.conf:`[my_ivr_menu]
  exten => s,1,AGI(/tmp/ivr.php,1)
  same => n,NoOp(hangup)
  same => n,Hangup`

Comment: @rajesh6115 Hi why is it not recommended to do db operation after hangup? any reason for that?

Comment: @Steven database insertion/update are time consuming, so it recommend not to use database calls in hangup handlers.
As always, hangup handlers, like the h extension, need to execute quickly because they are in the hangup sequence path of the call leg. Specific channel driver protocols like ISDN and SIP may not be able to handle excessive delays completing the hangup sequence.
for reference https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Handlers

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have a server with Asterisk, Digium card (FSX KS Signalling) and landlines installed. Customers can call our public phone number which is connected to my server to get IVR service.
I found that when user hangs up the call, asterisk doesn't send `SIGHUP` to my AGI script. It **does** work when IVR is called from internal network.

I finally solved it by adjusting some configurations in chan_dahdi.conf

```
busydetect=yes
busycount=3
```

Hope this helps if you have similar situation with me!